# Android theme properties partially switching between light and dark colors

Tags: android, material-design, android-theme

I am working on building a Light/Dark theme for my app. I want to use a custom shape for the all buttons in the app. But when swapping between themes, the `colorAccent` attribute isn't swapped for the button background color.

In the light mode, the `colorAccent` is ***Orange*** and it displays orange.

[image]

But in dark mode, the `colorAccent` is ***Purple*** but it still shows ***Orange***

[image]

I know that the swapping is working, because I can change other colors and they get adopted. It's just the button shape.

I'm sure it has something to do with `<solid android:color="@color/colorAccent" />` in the shape file.

Can anyone see what I am doing wrong?

**Light Theme**

```
<resources>
   <!--Top level DayNight theme to be used in AndroidManifest.xml-->
    <style name="MyCustomTheme" parent="Base.MyCustomTheme"/>

    <style name="MyCustomTheme.System.Defaults" parent="Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="android:fontFamily">@font/driver_font_family</item>
    </style>


    <style name="Base.MyCustomTheme" parent="MyCustomTheme.System.Defaults">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/OffWhite</item>

        <!--Component styles-->
        <item name="buttonStyle">@style/MyCustomTheme.Button</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

**Night Theme**

```
<resources>
    <style name="MyCustomTheme" parent="Base.MyCustomTheme">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/Green</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/Red</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/Purple</item>
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/BlackDark</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

**rounded_corners.xml**

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <corners  android:radius="10dp" />
    <padding  android:padding="0dp"/>
    <solid android:color="@color/colorAccent" />
</shape>
```

**colors.xml**

```
<resources>
    <!--Leaving these here since they are refrenced by the system and other components-->
    <color name="colorPrimary">@color/NavyBlue</color>
    <color name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/NavyBlueDark</color>
    <color name="colorAccent">@color/Orange</color>

    <color name="Red">#E84E3C</color>
    <color name="Purple">#745EC4</color>
    <color name="Green">#2FCC70</color>
    <color name="NavyBlue">#34495E</color>
    <color name="NavyBlueDark">#2B3D4F</color>
    <color name="BlueDark">#394D82</color>    
    <color name="OffWhite">#EDF1F2</color>
    <color name="BlackDark">#262626</color>
</resources>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is here:

```
<solid android:color="@color/colorAccent" />
```

In this way you are linking the **color** defined in `colors.xml` (which is `@color/Orange`). Instead you should link the **attribute** defined in the app theme:

Change to:

```
<solid android:color="?attr/colorAccent" />
```

Comment: Wow. I can’t believe I missed that. Thank you! I’ll accept the answer when the time restriction lifts.